# Representability of a functor in the category of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes, representable-functor

I have read in some places that a functor of points of a scheme is representable if its defined by locally closed or open conditions. I would like to ask for some references about this fact. I don´t know exactly what closed or open conditions are.

Comment: Do you mean the functor of points of a scheme?

Comment: Yes, that the functor is the functor of points of a scheme

Comment: I think probably this is just someone being imprecise. Obviously if you take a scheme $X$ and you take a locally closed subsceheme $Z$ that is 'cut out by locally closed conditions' then the functor satisfying those 'locally closed conditions' is represented by $Z$. Namely, one can try to define a 'locally closed embedding' of functors but its definition will almost certainly look like: $h\to h'$, a morphism of functors, is *locally closed* if for all representable $X$ the fiber product $h'\times_h X\to X$ is representable by a locally closed embedding. In particular, if $h\to Y$ is a locally

Comment: closed embedding with $Y$ representable then, by definition, $h\to Y$ is representable by a locally closed embedding (e.g. take $h'=Y$, $X=Y$, and $X\to h'$ the identity map in the above definition). Probably though if you just have a functor $h$ as a subfunctor of a scheme $X$ cut out by 'reasonable conditions' then it's probably not hard to show that it's a locally representable Zariski sheaf which is then representable (e.g. see Section 1.4 of Olsson's book *Algebraic spaces and stacks*).

Comment: Thank you for your time Alex Youcis.  Your comment has been so useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "I have read in some places that a functor of points of a scheme is representable if its defined by locally closed or open conditions. I would like to ask for some references about this fact. I don´t know exactly what closed or open conditions are."

**Answer:** If $F \in C:=Funct^{op}(Sch, Sets)$ is a functor we say $F$ is representable iff there is a scheme $X \in Sch$ and an "isomorpism of functors" $\eta: F \cong h_X$ where $h_X(S):=Mor_{Sch}(S,T)$ is the functor of points of $X$. Given a functor $F\in C$ we may speak of "open subfunctors" $U \subseteq F$ and an "open cover $U_i \subseteq F$" of $F$ by open subfunctors. There is the following criterium:

**Theorem:** A functor $F\in C$ is representable iff $F$ is a "sheaf in the Zariski topology" and there is an open cover $U_i$ of $F$ where $U_i \cong h_{X_i}$ are representable functors - represented by the schemes $X_i \in Sch$.

On the arXiv you find some papers of Vistoli on moduli functors and moduli spaces outlining this.